# FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. in firebase/firestore & react

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am working on firebase/firestore project where I created a firestore database and I am trying to implement in my react application
firestore v8.5
and react v17.0.2

I am receving this error and I could not find what is the issue
error

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new e (prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:188:1)
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10415:1
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10416:1
    at e.onMessage (prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10438:1)
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10355:1
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:10386:1
    at prebuilt-47338342-439a2133.js:15146:1
```

below shared my config file

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBTP_5W5stu00_FL57IVreIPlN616h-xI",
  authDomain: "javascript-tut-9a62.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://javascript-tut-9ac2-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "javascript-tut-96c2",
  storageBucket: "javascript-tut-9a62.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "31411032310",
  appId: "1:31110323110:web:e1d968ac4ded04bc300767"
}

// initialize firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// init services
const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore()

export { projectFirestore }
```

component Home.js

```
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { projectFirestore } from '../../firebase/config'

const Home = () => {
  const [ isPending, setIsPending ] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    projectFirestore.collection('recipe-app').get().then((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  return ( ... )
}

export default Home
```

please let me know what mistake I have made

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your [security rules](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/firestore/rules)?

Comment: I am new to firebase @Dharmaraj, could you please navigate me where can i check security rules?

Comment: You can click on the link in my previous comment and it should redirect you there.

Answer (score 0):

Change your storage rules from

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
 match /{allPaths=**} {
   allow read, write: if false;
  }
 }
}
```

to

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
 match /{allPaths=**} {
   allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```

Read about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security)